# How to get Rspec to use the same DB connection for reader and writer DB in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

For context, this question arose because we are migration from Rails 5 to Rails 6, and introducing reader / writer database connections via the new replication features.

Our specific problem is with request specs, with an eye towards using transactional fixtures.  When we run our request specs files in isolation, they pass.  When run as part of a multiple-file pass (such as a full `bundle exec parallel_rspec` pass used on circle CI) they fail.  If we turn off transactional fixtures, the tests take far too long to run, but pass.

Using `byebug`, we've poked in and determined that the problem is that our test data has been written to / is accessible by the writer DB connection, but the route is attempting to use the reader DB connection to read it.  I. E. `ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) { puts Foo.count }` is 0, while the same code connecting to writing role is non-zero.

The problem from there seems fairly obvious: because we're using transactional tests / fixtures, the code is never committed to the DB.  It's only available on the connection it was made on.  The request spec is reading from the 'right' db for the call (a GET request should use the reader db), but in the use-case of tests that's producing errors.

It seems like this is a fairly obvious use case that either Rails or rspec *should* have a tool for handling, we just don't seem to be able to find the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the test environment that it should be using a single connection for both. There are multiple ways of doing this:

1. You can configure your `test` environment not to use replicas at all. See [Setting up your application](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#setting-up-your-application) for examples of using a replica and not using a replica then reproduce the non-replica version in your `database.yml` for the test environment only.
2. You can use [`connected_to`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#using-manual-connection-switching) within your specs themselves so that those tests are forced to use the specific connection you want them to use. One way to do this is with [`around` hooks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/around-hooks#around-hooks-defined-in-a-group-are-run):

```rb
describe "around filter" do
  around(:each) do |example|
    puts "around each before"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :writing) { example.run }
    puts "around each after"
  end

  it "gets run in order" do
    puts "in the example"
  end
end
```

3. You can monkey patch your ActiveRecord configuration in `rails_helper` so that it doesn't use replicas (but I'd really recommend #1 over this option)

Comment: Thanks, the approach #2 worked for me in some simpler specs, still need to try it for more complex ones. However, I'm not sure how #1 would work. I still have to have multiple roles, and even if these roles point to the same DB configuration in test env, the transaction contexts are still different.