# RSpec: Looks like tests connect to the default reading role always

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

i have a model definition like below

```
class ExternalRecord < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  connects_to database: {
    writing: :main,
    reading:  :main,
    main: :main,
    main_red: :main_red,
    main_blue: :main_blue,
    main_green: :main_green
  }

end
```

application_record.rb

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
   connects_to database: { writing: :primary, reading: :primary }
end
```

below is my database.yml

```
test:
  primary:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: app_test
    database: "<%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>"
    username: "<%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>"
    password: "<%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"
    host: "<%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>"
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  main:
    adapter: postgresql
    username: user
    database: main
    password: pass
    host: 1.1.1.1
    database_tasks: false
    replica: false
  main_red:
    adapter: postgresql
    username: postgres
    database: main
    password: root
    host: localhost
    database_tasks: false
    replica: false
  main_blue:
    adapter: postgresql
    username: user
    database: main
    password: pass
    host: 2.2.2.2
    database_tasks: false
    replica: false
  main_green:
    adapter: "postgresql"
    username: "postgres"
    database: "<%= ENV['API_MAIN_GREEN_DATABASE_NAME'] %>"
    password: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"
    host: "<%= ENV['API_DATABASE_HOST'] %>"
    database_tasks: false
    replica: false
```

in a controller i have the following code

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :main_blue) do
end
```

The problem i am facing is when executing tests using rspec, the database that gets connected to is :main, irrespective of what role is provide above.

However, this works in dev environment and i get connected to the correct database based on role.

Any help on what could be going wrong in test env would be great, thanks.

Comment: Did you try `around` block? (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75289300/3452582)